# form_for , undefined method name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I want to add a comment model to my rails project but i got error in the render page saying:

## error:

```
Showing /Users/sovanlandy/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/shared/_comment_form.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `comment_content' for #<Comment:0x007fd0aa5335b8>
```

. Here are the related code

## comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :comment_content

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :micropost

validates :comment_content, presence: true
validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :micropost_id, presence: true  
end
```

## micropost.rb

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :content
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
.....
end
```

## user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
has_many :comments
....
end
```

## comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

 def create
@micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
@comment = @micropost.comments.build(params[:comment])
@comment.micropost = @micropost
@comment.user = current_user

if @comment.save
   flash[:success] = "Comment created!"z
   redirect_to current_user
else
  render 'shared/_comment_form'
end
end

end
```

## Partial of _comment_form_html.erb

```
<%= form_for([micropost, @comment]) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.text_field :comment_content, place_holder: "Comment" %>
 </div>
  <button class="btn" type="submit">
   Create
 </button>
 <% end %>
```

I called the patial _comment_form.html.erb from _micropost.html.erb class

```
     <%= render 'shared/comment_form', micropost: micropost %>
```

I also put comment as nested resource in route.rb

```
  resources :microposts do
    resources :comments
  end
```

How to resolve the error?
Thanks!

Comment: are you sure you have comment_content field in database?

Comment: @pavel : you are right... I forgot to run migration command. So noob of me... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Did you create the corresponding migrations for Comment a ran it? The error says that it's trying to access a method that don't exist. That means that you write wrong the name of the field or that you did not run the migrations that adds that field to your model. Could you copy the section of comments table from schema.rb?

Comment: You are right, I forgot to migrate my db so the comment_content does not have in db...

Answer (score 0):

try this in your `micropost.rb` write

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
  attr_accessible :comments_attributes
  ...
end
```

and in your `_comment_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @micropost do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :comments do |comment| %>
      ...
      <div class="field>
          <%= comment.text_field :comment_content, place_holder: "Comment" %>
      </div>
      ...
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Just want to hight light it seems that the form_for does not regconize my comment_content inside comment.rb and thought it is a method defined somewhere which it could not found. I think it is aligned to what you think as well...

Comment: Hmm this time it doesn't regconized @micropost.
it said:
    undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
Extracted source (around line #1):


1: <%= form_for @micropost do |f| %>
2:   <%= f.fields_for :comments do |comment| %>
3:    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
4:    <div class="field">

Comment: thanks now i got it working. I didn't migrate my db properly so it does not have comment_content column. Cheer>