# what am I doing wrong? undefined method `comment_content'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

I followed this page step-by-step
[Micropost's comments on users page (Ruby on Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669221/microposts-comments-on-users-page-ruby-on-rails)

then I looked into my error that I'm getting here
[form_for , undefined method name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985940/form-for-undefined-method-name)

I ran "rails generate migration add_comment_content_to_micropost comment_content:text"
then ran "rake db:migrate"

However, I'm still getting the undefined method `comment_content'error

```
NoMethodError in Users#show

Showing C:/app/views/shared/_comment_form.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `comment_content' for #<Comment:0x4fe56b8>
```

Here's the section where the column is from schema.db

```
create_table "microposts", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
    t.text     "commentcontent"
    t.text     "comment_content"
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is referring to a `Comment` object, not a `Micropost` object.  In your show method you need to refer to the correct object.

Looking at the post you refer to you've made a few mistakes.  For example the `Comment` class should have the `comment_content` field, not the `Micropost`.

I don't think you've created the models correctly.  For example your `Comment` model should have a `user_id` and a `micropost_id` to satisfy the `belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to :micropost` relationships.

Comment: do you mind showing me how to refer to the correct object? I followe this step-by-step here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669221/microposts-comments-on-users-page-ruby-on-rails

Comment: That question leaves some information out, assuming you know how to do migrations for the relationships between `Comment`, `Micropost`, and `User`. I edited my answer for an example.

Comment: I was able to work through most of the issue but now I'm getting the word "Asset" displayed right above the commenting box. Do you know why that occurs? I couldn't find any relevant searches on this error where the text "Asset" is showing up

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like you have set associations in your `model` wrongly.
Please visit here to know the way to make associations.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html